# Forward slash (/) character in SAP Vora table columns

Tags: sap-bw, vora

I've got data from a SAP BW InfoProvider written to HDFS. Now I'm trying to make that data available for reporting in Vora 1.3.

I'm trying to run a statement in Vora Tools SQL console, starting with:

```
CREATE TABLE F002_5_F (calyear string, 
    calmonth string, 
    /bic/zfiscweek string, 
    doc_currcy string,
    co_area string, 
    /bic/zbillamt decimal(17,2),
    ......)
USING com.sap.spark.vora
OPTIONS (.....
```

And upon execution Vora reports a syntax error in lines for fields with names containing "/bic/" part.
As a workaround, I tried quoting field names, e.g. "/bic/zfiscweek". But then Vora reported a syntax error in the line "USING com.sap.spark.vora".

Any comment on how field names with "/" character should be treated in Vora modelling?

Comment: Just tried this in Vora 1.4, as I got it working. Still no support for "/" character, even though it's supported by Hive and Spark SQL. Seriously, this is a BIG functionality gap, I've seen BW architects on customer's side laughing in disbelief at this. They look to offload their BW corporate memory data to Vora and won't be able to do it until this is fixed. @FrankLegler

Answer (score 0):

Quoted column names are not supported. You have to replace the slash "/" with another character so that the column name becomes a valid SQL identifier.

Comment: as I am supposed to load data from ORC files that's been generated by SAP BW archiving process (NLS on Hadoop), I don't have a choice to replace the forward-slash with anything. This seems to be a functionality gap in Vora.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the column names with backticks.

```
CREATE TABLE SLASHTABLE (`/A1` double, `/A2` int, `/A3` string) 
USING com.sap.spark.vora 
OPTIONS (files "/user/vora/test.csv");
```

This also works in SELECT queries:

```
SELECT `/A1` from SLASHTABLE;
```